# Чому інколи українські перекладачі змінюють назву фільму?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Давно мене вже цікавить питання чому переклади назв деяких фільмів зовсім не співпадають із їхніми оригінальними назвами.

Наприклад фільм "[Die hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard)" переклали як "[Міцний горішок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%86%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA)", хоч насправді в назві не йдеться ні про які "міцні горіхи". І взагалі вислів "[Die hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_hard_(phrase))" - це фраза сказана Вільямом Інглісом і перекласти її можна як "Тримайтеся до останнього подиху", "Не здавайтеся", "Стійте насмерть" (офіцер закликав своїх солдат тримати оборону до кінця). Ну якщо тут ще можна подумати, що перекладачі просто хотіли зробити коротку і захоплюючу назву для фільму, то з фільмом "Four Brothers" ("Чотири брати") і його перекладом "Кров за кров" взагалі не зрозуміло. І таких випадків чимало:

"Ted" ("Тед" - назва ведмедя) - "Третій зайвий"

"The Guard" ("Охорона") - "Ірландець"

Тощо

Чи є якесь правило, яке дозволяє виконувати такий переклад? І для чого це взагалі робиться?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Це не переклад - це місцевий маркетинг. Люди, що займаються кінопрокатом вважають що глядач не піде на фільм з назвою "Охорона", а "Ірландець" публіку зацікавить. Є студії (як наприклад "Дісней" або "Піксар") які пильно контролюють процес перекладу своїх фільмів/мультфільмів - тоді місцевий прокат не може втрутитися і перекласти назву "задньою лівою".

Насправді така (або схожа) політика щодо назв є у багатьох країнах. Наприклад спільний англо-американський фільм із оригінальною назвою "Hummingbird" ("Колібрі") у США вийшов із назвою "Redemption" ("Спокута"), у Великобританії "Hummingbird", у Хорватії "Iskuplenije", у Франції "Crazy Joe" (Joey - ім'я головного героя), в Україні "Ефект колібрі", в Угорщині "Kolibri-kód". (Інформація з сайту [imdb.com](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1893256/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_sa_2#akas)). Пишуть що місцева фірма узгоджує переклад із студією-виробником, але в такому разі, як бачимо, результат залежить від смаку місцевого дистрибутора і ступеня прискіпливості студії-виробника.

Іноді таке ставлення до назви призводить до подальших складнощів коли (як це часто трапляється з голівудським кіно) виходить продовження. Наприклад був фільм із оригінальною назвою "[The Hangover](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119646/releaseinfo#akas)" ("Похмілля"), який переклали "Похмілля у Вегасі" (тому що події розгорталися у Лас Вегасі). Потім через два роки виходить "[The Hangover II](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411697/releaseinfo#akas)", де події розгортаються у Тайланді. Фільм отримав локальну назву "Похмiлля-2: з Вегаса до Бангкока".